# Retaining newlines in PowerShell string

Tags: string, powershell, newline

In a PowerShell script, I'm capturing the string output of an EXE file in a variable, then concatenating it with some other text to build an email body.

However, when I do this I find that the newlines in the output are reduced to spaces, making the total output unreadable.

```
# Works fine
.\other.exe

# Works fine
echo .\other.exe

# Works fine
$msg = other.exe
echo $msg

# Doesn't work -- newlines replaced with spaces
$msg = "Output of other.exe: " + (.\other.exe)
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps this helps:

```
$msg = "Output of other.exe: " + "`r`n" + ( (.\other.exe) -join "`r`n")
```

You get a list of lines and not a text from other.exe

```
$a = ('abc', 'efg')
 "Output of other.exe: " + $a


 $a = ('abc', 'efg')
 "Output of other.exe: " +  "`r`n" + ($a -join "`r`n")
```

Answer (score 16):

Or you could simply set $OFS like so:

```
PS> $msg = 'a','b','c'
PS> "hi $msg"
hi a b c
PS> $OFS = "`r`n"
PS> "hi $msg"
hi a
b
c
```

From `man about_preference_variables`:

Output Field Separator. Specifies the character that separates the
elements of an array when the array is converted to a string.

Comment: Upvoting this, because only after your answer did I grok that `$msg` isn't being set to a single string, but an *array of lines* which are by default concatenated with spaces.

Comment: Great time saver and hidden gem. Excellent!

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use for Out-String

```
Write-Output "My IP info: $(ipconfig.exe | Out-String)"

My IP info:
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 2222::2222:2222:2222:5150%4
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.155
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```