# Preserve newlines when concatenating or using heredoc in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have the a document `c:\temp\temp.txt` with contents

```
line 1
line 2
```

and I create the following function

```
PS>function wrapit($text) {
@"
---Start---
$text
---End---
"@
}
```

Then running `PS> wrapit((Get-Content c:\temp\temp.txt))`

will output

```
---Start---
line 1 line 2
---End---
```

How do I preserve newlines? Appending versus interpolating doesn't help.

[I found this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431706/retaining-newlines-in-powershell-string), but here they are using a string array. I am using a single string which has newline characters in it (you can see them if you output the string directly from inside the function without concatenating and `$text | gm` confirms I'm working with a string, not an array). I can do all the string parsing in the world to hammer it into place, but that seems like I'd be banging a square peg in a round hole. What is the concept that I'm missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple way to do what you want is:

```
wrapit((Get-Content c:\temp\temp.txt | out-string))
```

Now the explanation: Here-strings @"" just behave like strings "" and the result is due to the PowerShell behaviour in variables expansion. Just try:

```
$a = Get-Content c:\temp\temp.txt
"$a"
```

---

Regarding your comment:

```
$a | Get-Member
TypeName: System.String
...
```

But

```
Get-Member -InputObject $a
TypeName: System.Object[]
...
```

The first answer is OK (it receives strings). It just does not repeat System.string each time. In the second it receive an array as parameter.

Comment: If I'm correct, it seems to be mostly a matter of type coercion. Which is fine, I'm just confused why on earth `Get-Member` told me the type was a `System.String`

Comment: Oooooh, that's right, I always forget how the pipe does that. Dang. Most of the time its right on, this time it confused me for hours.

Answer (score 8):

Son of a...

Upon investigation it seems that `Get-Content` returns a string array. Which is of course coerced to a string by default by joining on the default character `' '`.

What is really puzzling is why the results are coerced by `get-member` to a string. **Anyone know why that would happen?** The issue wasn't obvious until I explicitly checked `Get-Type`

In any case, the solution was to read the file using `[system.io.file]::ReadAllText('c:\temp\temp.txt')` over `Get-Content`

Comment: yeah it automatically unwraps arrays and shows the type of the _type_ of the array, if that makes sense.

Comment: use `$var.gettype()` to tell what type a variable actually is

Comment: `Get-Content -raw` seems to do the trick as well. It requires PS >= 3.

Comment: `Get-Content -raw` did it! Thanks!