# String in Output is concatenated in one line although the original string is not concatenated - why?

Tags: powershell, string-concatenation

My problem is related to PowerShell 4.0 (Win7).

The goal is to get a chosen multiline string out of a textfile together with another prepared text.

I'm using the following code:

```
$nl = [System.Environment]::NewLine
[string]$text1 = 'Hello World' + $nl
$b = (Get-Content textfile.txt | Out-GridView -OutputMode Multiple)
```

Content of textfile.txt:

```
tester 1  
tester 2  
tester 3
```

I choose tester 1 and tester 2 from GridView and click OK
An output of $b gives me the following (expected) result in 2 separate lines:

```
        $b  
tester 1  
tester 2
```

So far, so good

Now I'm putting the strings together with:

```
$test = $text1 + $b
```

An output of $test gives me the following (unexpected) result:

```
        $test  
Hello World  
tester 1 tester 2
```

Question:
Why is the output of $test not in 2 separate lines as was the output of $b ??

I wanted it to be:

```
Hello World  
tester 1  
tester 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. I found the solution in the following post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4433240/9033281

I had to set the "Output Field Separator" like so:

```
$OFS = "`r`n"
```

Thank you, Keith Hill :-)