# Run local python script on remote server thanks to Posh-SSH module (W10)

Tags: python, powershell, ssh, posh-ssh

I want to run local python script on remote server **by using Posh-SSH** which is a module in Powerhsell.
This [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499074/run-local-python-script-on-remote-server) mention it with regular ssh by doing this:

```
Get-Content hello.py | ssh user@192.168.1.101 python -
```

I would like here to use Posh-SSH module but I don't get how to achieve it...

I tried sth like this but it doesn't work

```
Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command "$(Get-Content hello.py) | python3 -u -" -ErrorAction Stop
```

**EDIT**

No errors shown, only stuck on it and and do nothing...

**EDIT2**

Ok I get it now why I have this error when I send a multiline py file.

New lines are not retranscripted, look what command will be send to the remote server :

```
python3 -u - <<"--ENDOFPYTHON--"
chevre="basic" print("Hello, World!")
--ENDOFPYTHON--
```

and not:

```
python3 -u - <<"--ENDOFPYTHON--"
chevre="basic" 
print("Hello, World!")
--ENDOFPYTHON--
```

**EDIT3**

And finally Done !
Thanks to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431706/retaining-newlines-in-powershell-string) I performed to change the whitespace to newline as it should be.
For doing this just to this

```
( (Get-Content hello.py) -join "`r`n")
```

instead of simple

```
$(Get-Content hello.py)
```

Finally the line will be :

```
$cmd = "python3 -u - <<`"--ENDOFPYTHON--`"`n$((Get-Content $pyscript) -join "`r`n")`n--ENDOFPYTHON--"
Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command $cmd -ErrorAction Stop
```

**Also don't forget to remove the line**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

if present on top of your py file, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? We need more information to help

Comment: No errors...just stuck there and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently sending the following to the SSH endpoint:

```sh
# Example Python Added: would be replaced with your code
print("Hello, World!") | python3 -u -
```

Assuming bash as the endpoint shell, the above is invalid and would either produce an error or hang.

You need to encapsulate the code being sent to the server using `echo` (assuming bash ssh endpoint).

```
Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command "echo '$((Get-Content hello.py) -join "`r`n")' | python3 -u -" -ErrorAction Stop
```

The above will now send:

```sh
echo 'print("Hello, World!")' | python3 -u -
```

This works as long as you don't use single quotes. However, if you must use those or other special characters, you may need to use a here document instead:

```
Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command "python3 -u - <<`"--ENDOFPYTHON--`"`n$((Get-Content hello.py) -join "`r`n")`n--ENDOFPYTHON--" -ErrorAction Stop
```

The here document will send exactly what it is to the standard input stream of the program: tabs, spaces, quotes and all. Therefore the above will send the following:

```sh
python3 -u - <<"--ENDOFPYTHON--"
print("Hello, World!")
--ENDOFPYTHON--
```

You can replace `--ENDOFPYTHON--` with anything as long as it does not appear in your python file.

[Reference for here docs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

## UPDATE:

Added `` -join "`r`n" `` as it is needed for newlines to be sent correctly, as pointed out by the asker.

Comment: Seems not bad !! Even though I still have an issue. At the moment where my py file do more than one line, I have an exit code 1... I tried to understand docs you put in link but I didn't undersand all of it, maybe somwhere it mention it...

Comment: Know why now. Take a look on the edit Once this issue is done everything will be  perfect I think !

Comment: Ah yeah I didn't think about new lines. I've added it into my answer